# Printing out the email address of sender from InternetAddress

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

This is the code that fetches up the `sender` and the `subject` of email.With this code i see the correct subject getting displayed but i see the address of the sender in different format.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.imap.host" , "imap.gmail.com" );
    props.put("mail.imap.user" , "username");
    // User SSL
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory" , 993);
    props.put("mail.imap.socketFactory.class" , "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
    props.put("mail.imap.port" , 993 );
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props , new Authenticator() {
        @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("username" , "password");
        }
    });

    try {
      Store store = session.getStore("imap");
      store.connect("imap.gmail.com" , "username" , "password");
      Folder fldr = store.getFolder("Inbox");
      fldr.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
      Message msgs[] = fldr.getMessages();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < msgs.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println(msgs[i].getFrom() + "<-- FROM" + " " + msgs[i].getSubject() + "<---Subject");
        }
    } catch(Exception exc) {

    }
}
```

The output is :

```
[Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@1462851<-- FROMGet Gmail on your mobile phone<---Subject
[Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@bdab91<-- FROMImport your contacts and old email<---Subject
[Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@4ac00c<-- FROMCustomize Gmail with colors and themes<---Subject
[Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@1865b28<-- FROMtester<---Subject
```

**What form it is?***(@1462851)* 
I want the email address of sender to appear instead of `@1462851`.How can i do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `getFrom()` function returns a list of type `Address[]`. To have it printed as a plain string, please try `InternetAddress.toString(msgs[i].getFrom())` in your `System.out`.

Answer (score 4):

I've spent some hard minutes before I found out this simple code:

`System.out.println("received from "+((InternetAddress)((Address)(message.getFrom()[0]))).getAddress());`

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`msgs[i].getFrom().getAddress()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getAddress%28%29). What you see is the `toString` result of `InternetAddress` object (class name + hashcode)

Comment: i get error when i do this. it says cannot find symbol method `getAddress()`

Comment: this is odd, no offense, but please make sure you don't have a typo. can you show that part of the code?

Comment: HI! For me too its giving errors.seems this has been deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because you just print out the `InternetAddress` instance, which does not have a `toString()` method.  Then it defaults to the `Object.toString()` which is primarily useful to see if objects are different.

Consider explicitly picking out the field you want to see in your print statement.