# Condition gets false even if it contains specified data

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to process mails using JAVA MAIL API. I want to check emails which comes **from** particular email id , So I am checking like :

```
   for(int i=0;i<messages.length;i++)
   {
       if(messages[i].getFrom().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("seller-notification@amazon.com"))
       {
           System.out.println(messages[i].getContent());

           Multipart mp = (Multipart)messages[i].getContent();  
           Object Body = mp.getBodyPart(i).getContent();
           String Content = Body.toString();
       }
```

}

Debug Mode Screen , I can see in debug that values is there in **from** :

[image]

Above condition is not getting true.

Comment: There string seems to start with the name, then the email address...  Did you mean: `messages[i].getFrom().toString().toLowerCase().contains("seller-notification@amazon.com");`?

Comment: it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806449/printing-out-the-email-address-of-sender-from-internetaddress

Comment: @assylias - I tried this way also , but did not work.

Comment: Try adding `String s = messages[i].getFrom().toString();`, and then look in the debugger and see what `s` is.  If that doesn't help you figure out the problem, then post the value of `s` so we can look at it.

Comment: toString implementation won't return what he wants,

Comment: @ajb - `S` returns something like `[Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@7817fd62`

Comment: Yes, that explains it.  You're using `toString()` on an array, and that doesn't work.  I think the other answers show you how to get a value that you _can_ use as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it's not a string, and you are trying to compare an `Object`'s `toString()` method and a `String`. Since this `toString` won't return what you want, you have to cast it to `Address` and fetch email from there.

Try:

```
Address[] froms = messages[i].getFrom();
String email = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();
if("seller-notification@amazon.com".equalsIgnoreCase(email))
{//Your work}
```

Comment: Is there any way to direct change in my condition? Or I will have to store all getfrom in Addreess[] ?

Comment: Where is he trying to compare an `Object` and a `String`?  The original code used `toString()`, which returns a `String`, so I don't think that's the problem.  Plus, your suggested code will possibly set `email` to `null` and then try to use `email.equalsIgnoreCase` which will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: As you  can notify in debug scren it returns an `InternetAddress` array which has size of 1. Therefore that's the only way.

Comment: @ajb thanks for notifying I've edited my answer, when he calls toString(), it doesnt return the wished string to be compared....

Comment: @SercanOzdemir - Actually there are many email addresses but I have taken that deug screenshot by run loop only 1 time so.

Comment: No, I'm not talking about email addresses, I'm talking about `messages[i].getFrom()` method's return.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the toString generates "[Seller Notification ]", and this is not equals to "seller-notification@amazon.com".

You should cast to InternetAddress (check before just in case), extract the email and check the email.

Answer (score 0):

.getFrom() method returns an array of Address datatype object. So first you have to select one of the array elements and cast it to InternetAddress datatype. See the code below

```
if(((InternetAddress)(messages[i].getFrom()[0])).getAddress().equalsIgnoreCase("seller-notification@amazon.com"))
{
    //your remaining code
}
```

Please mark this as answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

messages[i].getFrom().toString()** only give byte value..)-you need to convert to string using this line

```
        InternetAddress.toString(messages[i].getFrom());
```